# Survey statistic diagram ideas

Tags: javascript, statistics, diagram, survey

I've got some homework tasks in topic surveys and diagrams. The first task is to normalize the input of a survey, because the structure of the data is changing from time-to-time.
So there are three types of surveys:

- static fields, where text is stored
- dynamic ones, where the user can select one option
- and multiselect fields, where the user can select multiple options

So I'm not really a statistics guy, so I have really no idea what I can do with that incomming data.

So the data I have is stored in an huge XML file from there I can easily get how man times a survey was filled, and how many times a field was filled, so I can (for eg on a pie chart show the relation of filled or not filled).
The second idea is to show the relation between the content of a multi option element using a bar chart or so.

In case of the multi option elements I've got the idea to show data in implication of one option.
But the question is, what could be shown?

The other problem are the static elements (text fields and so). What data could be represented from a single field?

The data in the XML field is collected from 2001 to 2005 So maybe I can work with the dates of the surveys, but as I said, I don't really know how to process the data, to collect as much as possible, to create a really great amount of diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

After normalizing your data (which could be more difficult than the visualizing part of your job), you might do the followings:

- To show your static fields, which contains texts, you could recode theese text to new variables containing fewer categories, which could fit on a graph/plot. Another way is to make word clouds of the texts - like on [wordle.net](http://www.wordle.net/gallery).
- The dynamic fields, each containing only one answere, could be the easiest to display. You could make a pie chart to show the percentages of the attributes, or rather a bar chart which could also display percentages/densities or frequencies (e.g. see the [ggplot2](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_bar.html) package in R).
- To display the multiselect fields, you should restructure the date to the appropriate format (I do not know how it looks like now). This could be done by different tables, that show the counts (frequencies) for every categories in all variables. E.g.: 187 people ate choclate, 160 ate bread and 50 people ate pizza yesterday. You could then show the values by a barchart easily. Look out for: the sum of theese vaules will not equal to the sample size, as anyone could select multiple values, so a pie chart would be a really bad choice.

I hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend pie charts. Use bar charts or dot plots instead. It is much easier to distinguish similar frequencies for different categories in them. Ordering the categories by frequencies in them is almost always a good idea, too. Here you can find a short article about why [Pie Charts Are Bad](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Pie-Charts-Are-Bad/).

3D diagrams might look nice and are a neat way of impressing people with little knowledge about data visialization (which might be what you need ;-) ). But they are considered bad practice by most experts, because using extra dimensions, which are not absolutely needed, distracts the reader from the actual data.

Personally I think that crosstables and [scatter plots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scatter_plot) are pretty self-explanatory ways of displaying relationships between two dimensions of data.

It is often a good idea to report some basic statistics along with diagrams, but make sure you only do this when it's appropriate. See this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levels_of_measurement) if you want to learn, which univariate statistics (like a mean for example) are appropriate for which data.

If you seriously want to learn about data visualization, I can highly recommend the [books by Edward Tufte](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/books_vdqi) about the topic. They are really a pleasure to read. While they stand on a solid scientific base, they are easy to understand, even with little or no background in the field.

Good luck,
Alex